# Error Code 0xe0f00013 during recovery of HP laptop

Tags: windows-7, restore

I have an HP DV6-2071EE, and I would like to performa a recovery using the Recovery DVDs.

It gives me the error:

> Recovery Manager couldn't restore your computer using the factory image. Please contact HP Support. Error Code: 0xe0f00013

Comment: Are you using the recovery disks sent by HP or the ones you created yourself? Also, did you wipe/clean the hard drive, or is the hard drive fairly new?

Answer (score 1):

First test your memory and hard drive, at the HP splash screen when you first power up, tap ESC key repeatedly to get the HP boot screen, run the diagnostics on the hard drive and memory, post back any errors. Diagnostics can also be found in the bios using F10.

If you are using HP branded Recovery discs and changed the partitions, blanked the hard drive or are installing to a new hard drive, [download this utility](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=pv-80183-1&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en) to make a bootable disc, boot from it and run the repair tool, then start a fresh recovery using your Recovery discs.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a work around if you have ( or can borrow ) a retail Windows 7 installation disc that is exactly the same version as your OEM installation - ie if your notebook came with Windows 7 Home Premium 64bit this is the exact retail version you would need.

If you don't have access to a retail disc, you can create an installation disc yourself - just download the correct Disc Image from the link below and use an application such as ImgBurn to burn the ISO correctly to a blank DVD.

http://www.mydigitallife.info/download-windows-7-iso-official-32-bit-and-64-bit-direct-download-link...

Use the disc to perform the installation, enter the Windows activation key found on the underside of your notebook when requested and when the installation has completed, use the 'Phone Method' detailed in the link below to activate the OS - this method supported by Microsoft and is popular with people who just want a clean installation of Windows 7 without the additional software load normally bundled with OEM installations.

http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/how-to-activate-windows-7-by-phone.aspx